# Alfresco SOLR4 not giving results if I use wildcard search on a text field having comma separated numbers

Tags: search, solr, wildcard, alfresco

I am using SOLR4 along with Alfresco 5 application

I have a text field called field1 with value : 71,72,73
If I search for 
    @field1:72
 I get the results. 
But if I search for 
    @field1:*72* 
I am not getting results.

What changes I need to do in the configs to get the results.

I have below configurations set on my schema.xml

```
<fieldType name="text___" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
     <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.ICUTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="org.apache.solr.analysis.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
                generateWordParts="1"
                generateNumberParts="1"
                catenateWords="1"
                catenateNumbers="1"
                catenateAll="1"
                splitOnCaseChange="1"
                splitOnNumerics="1"
                preserveOriginal="1"
                stemEnglishPossessive="1"/>
        <filter class="solr.ICUFoldingFilterFactory"/>
     </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

UPDATE : After further analysis this looks to me a limitation of minimum number of characters that SOLR accepts for searching. If I use more than 2 characters I can get the results. For example in the above

@field1:*72,* Gives me the results. If I use just asterisk then also it works but not if I use 1 or 2 characters like 7* or 72* won't work.

UPDATE 2 : This time I tried with a text field having values "123456". If I search for 
1*
12*
123*
1234*

I am not getting results. But I can get the results only if I give 12345* 
I can also get results if I give 123456*

I am sure this worked fine in older solr version 4.9 but broken in 4.10

Comment: Did you checked the same on the solr analysis page? Wild card will not work with text fieldtype...check with string as field type

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti SOLR analysis page is showing the right tokens but my guess is wild card search is not going through analysis so can't rely on analysis page results. I don't have a field type as string in my analysis page.

Comment: Add a string field. Index data to it. Check the same on the analysis for the string field.

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti I cannot use string as sometimes I need to search with query that matches the tokens rather than using wildcard search.

Comment: You can have 2 fields and they can be indexed with different field type. One can be indexed with string field type and other can be of text_ general type which will create the required tokens for you.

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti somehow in my analysis page I can't use wildcard to search it always strips it and always give me a match with the token but it fails when I try it out in query

Comment: Please share the details of the same with screenshot.