# Alfresco SOLR4 Wild card search not working if minimum 1 or 2 characters used for search

Tags: solr, alfresco

I am using SOLR4 (4.10.3) which comes along with Alfresco and there are no customizations in the SOLR with all default configurations.

I have a field called fieldOne:72,73,74

If I search for Query @fieldOne:*72* It does not produce any result
Same with If I search for @fieldOne:*7*

But If I use 3 characters then it works as @fieldOne:*72,*

I would like to know where this is configured to update this settings to allow the search to use minimum 2 characters to fetch the results.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Alfresco SOLR4 not giving results if I use wildcard search on a text field having comma separated numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60182835/alfresco-solr4-not-giving-results-if-i-use-wildcard-search-on-a-text-field-havin)

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti Unfortunately No. I tried using copyfield and create a new string field and did reindexing and hit search but not results.